# El método tiene que retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de libros del emprendedor(función constructora)

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, class, constructor, push

Tengo una función constructora de la siguiente forma:

```
 function crearClaseEmprendedor() {
```

class Emprendedor {

```
  constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {

      // El constructor de la clase Emprendedor recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), libros (array de objetos), mascotas (array de strings)

      // Inicializar las propiedades del emprendedor con los valores recibidos como argumento

      // Tu código aca:
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.libros = libros;
      this.mascotas = mascotas;


  }
```

Y tengo un método que debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de libros del emprendedor.

Ejemplo: Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estos libros:

```
[
    {nombre: 'El señor de las moscas',autor: 'William Golding'},
    {nombre: 'Fundacion', autor: 'Isaac Asimov'}
]
```

`emprendedor.getBooks()` debería devolver `['El señor de las moscas', 'Fundacion']`

Hice un arreglo nuevo y le apliqué un `push` pero no me retorna el arreglo con solo los nombres de los libros

```
getBooks() {
         let arreglo1 = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < this.libros.length; i++){

    arreglo1.push(this.libros[i].nombre);

  }
        return arreglo1
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el mensaje completo.

Comment: ok ahí trato de especificar un poco más

Comment: Por favor vuelve a editar la pregunta y pon todo el código de la clase. Por ahora, lo único que veo raro es que no hay un `return arreglo1;` y seguramente obtienes `undefined` en vez del arreglo que esperas.

Comment: Además de lo que dice Triby, también te falta declarar `arreglo1` con un `let` o un `var` delante.

Comment: ok un segundo hago modificaciones

Comment: Si me da, gracias, jaja ando modo zombie perdón

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay necesidad de crear un arreglo ni usar el bucle for, para esto puedes utilizar el método `.map()` que recorrerá el arreglo libros y devolverá un arreglo con los nombre.

```js
class Emprendedor {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {  
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.apellido = apellido;
  this.libros = libros;
  this.mascotas = mascotas;
  }
  
  getNameBooks(){
    return this.libros.map(item => item.nombre);
  }
}

const emprendedor = new Emprendedor('Juan', 'Paz', [{nombre: 'El señor de las moscas',autor: 'William Golding'}, {nombre: 'Fundacion', autor: 'Isaac Asimov'}], ['Scooby', 'Dollar'])

console.log(emprendedor.getNameBooks());
```